# A way to read data out of a file at compile time to put it somewhere in application image files to initialize an array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file, compiler-construction, initialization

considering visual C++ compiler, Lets say I've got a file with whatever extension and it contains 100 bytes of data which are exactly the data that I want to initialize an array of char data type with a length of 100 characters with, Now apparently one way is to read those data out of file by using I/O file classes or APIs at run-time but what I want to know is that, is there any way using directives or something to tell the compiler I want to put that data in a right place in my application image files at compile time and compiler should go read those data out of that file?

Comment: There is an "embed" proposal for that: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1040r6.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Write a program that reads the 100 byte data file and generates as output, a file, with c++ code/syntax for declaring an array with the 100 bytes in the file.
- Include this new generated file(inline) in your main c++ file.
- Call the c++ compiler on the main c++ file.

Answer (score 2):

You do this with a resource in a Windows program.  Right-click the project, Add, Resource, Import.  Give the custom resource type a name.  Edit the resource ID, if necessary.  Get a pointer to the resource data at runtime with FindResource and LoadResource.

Comment: Does the compiler examine the resource at compile time ?

Comment: The resource compiler, yes.  Not much examining going on, it just embeds the bytes.

Comment: You tell that still using a function like FindResource or LoadResource is required and that would be done at run-time, I meant a solution at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

What I frequently use in testing for **textual data** is I create a `std::istringstream` object containing the text of the file to be read like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

// raw string literal for easy pasting in
// of textual file data
std::istringstream internal_config(R"~(

# Config file

host: wibble.org
port: 7334
// etc....

)~");

// std::istream& can receive either an ifstream or an istringstream
void read_config(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(is, line))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // did the user pass a filename to use?
    std::string filename;
    if(argc > 2 && std::string(argv[1]) == "--config")
        filename = argv[2];

    // if so try to use the file
    std::ifstream ifs;
    if(!filename.empty())
        ifs.open(filename);

    if(ifs.is_open())
        read_config(ifs);
    else
        read_config(internal_config); // file failed use internal config
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "filename"
```

or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: That is because the question has been edited since I answered.

Comment: @Dipstick_No, Edition didn't have anything to do with changing the core issue.

Comment: You didn't originally state that the data was in binary format. If it is then just convert it to comma separated hex ascii before hand then include that.

Comment: @Dipstick_Actually I did and that's why others proposed solutions regarding the matter.