# How to read data from a text file at compile time in this case?

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation

I know the title of the question might make it look to be a duplicate question but its not so. I have tried almost all the solutions given here on stackoverflow..[A way to read data out of a file at compile time to put it somewhere in application image files to initialize an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743120/a-way-to-read-data-out-of-a-file-at-compile-time-to-put-it-somewhere-in-applicat).

**My problem is I am using a C++ code and I am using some of the open cv libraries and functions as well. I have a main function OsiMain.cpp and this has the code as**

***My Code:***

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
try
{
    OsiManager osi ;        
    osi.loadConfiguration(argv[1]) ;
    osi.showConfiguration() ;        
    osi.run() ;
}
catch ( std::exception & e )
{
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl ;
    }

return 0 ;
```

OsiManager is another class.This class manages all the files, configuration, saving and loading options. It uses OsiEye class to execute technical processings.

In the OsiManager constructor we initialise the value of some of the parameters that the code will need. The constructor part of the OsiManager code is given below

```
// Default constructor
OsiManager::OsiManager ( )
{
    mMapInt["Minimum diameter for pupil"] = &mMinPupilDiameter ;
    mMapInt["Maximum diameter for pupil"] = &mMaxPupilDiameter ;
    mMapInt["Minimum diameter for iris"] = &mMinIrisDiameter ;
    mMapInt["Maximum diameter for iris"] = &mMaxIrisDiameter ;
    mMapInt["Width of normalized image"] = &mWidthOfNormalizedIris ;
    mMapInt["Height of normalized image"] = &mHeightOfNormalizedIris ;
    mMapString["Gabor filters"] = &mFilenameGaborFilters ;
    mMapString["Application points"] = &mFilenameApplicationPoints ;


    // Initialize all parameters
    initConfiguration() ;     
}

void OsiManager::initConfiguration ( )
{
    mMinPupilDiameter = 50;
    mMaxPupilDiameter = 160; 
    mMinIrisDiameter = 160; 
    mMaxIrisDiameter = 280; 
    mWidthOfNormalizedIris = 512; 
    mHeightOfNormalizedIris = 64; 
    mFilenameGaborFilters = "/home/Iris_Osiris_v4.1/OsirisParam/filters.txt" ;
    mFilenameApplicationPoints = "/home/Iris_Osiris_v4.1/OsirisParam/points.txt" ;
   mGaborFilters.clear();
   mpApplicationPoints = 0 ;
```

}

These values are getting initialized in the constructor. In the function *initconfiguration* we can see two file paths mfilenameGaborFilter and mfilenameApplication points. These give the paths of two file names. Thse files basically have huge matrices like 9 by 15 , 9 by 25. These matrices are being read into the variables mGaborFilters and mpApplicationPoints which are of type vectorCvMat* and CvMat* respectively.The functions being used to read these files into variables are given below as loadGaborFilters and loadApplicationPoints respectively.

```
void OsiManager::loadGaborFilters( )
{
    // Open text file containing the filters
    ifstream file(mFilenameGaborFilters.c_str(),ios::in) ;
    if ( ! file )
    {
        throw runtime_error("Cannot load Gabor filters in file " + mFilenameGaborFilters) ;
    }

    // Get the number of filters
    int n_filters ;
    file >> n_filters ;
    mGaborFilters.resize(n_filters) ;

    // Size of filter
    int rows , cols ;

    // Loop on each filter
    for ( int f = 0 ; f < n_filters ; f++ )
    {    
        // Get the size of the filter
        file >> rows ;
        file >> cols ;

        // Temporary filter. Will be destroyed at the end of loop
        mGaborFilters[f] = cvCreateMat(rows,cols,CV_32FC1) ;            

        // Set the value at coordinates r,c
        for ( int r = 0 ; r < rows ; r++ )
        {
            for ( int c = 0 ; c < cols ; c++ )
            {
                file >> mGaborFilters[f]->data.fl[r*cols+c] ;
            }
        }

    } // Loop on each filter

    // Close the file
    file.close() ;

} // end of function





// Load the application points (build a binary matrix) from a textfile
void OsiManager::loadApplicationPoints ( )
{
    // Open text file containing the filters
    ifstream file(mFilenameApplicationPoints.c_str(),ios::in) ;
    if ( ! file )
    {
        throw runtime_error("Cannot load the application points in " + mFilenameApplicationPoints) ;
    }

    // Get the number of points
    int n_points = 0 ;
    file >> n_points ;

    // Allocate memory for the matrix containing the points
    mpApplicationPoints = cvCreateMat(mHeightOfNormalizedIris,mWidthOfNormalizedIris,CV_8UC1) ;

    // Initialize all pixels to "off"
    cvSet(mpApplicationPoints,cvScalar(0)) ;        

    // Local variables
    int i , j ;

    // Loop on each point
    for ( int p = 0 ; p < n_points ; p++ )
    {    
        // Get the coordinates
        file >> i ; file >> j ;

        // Set pixel to "on"
        if ( i < 0 || i > mpApplicationPoints->rows-1 || j < 0 || j > mpApplicationPoints->cols-1 )
        {
            cout << "Point (" << i << "," << j << ") " ;
            cout << "exceeds size of normalized image : " ;
            cout << mpApplicationPoints->rows << "x" << mpApplicationPoints->cols ;
            cout << " while loading application points" << endl ;
        }
        else
        {
            mpApplicationPoints->data.ptr[(i)*mpApplicationPoints->cols+j] = 255 ;
        }
    }

    // Close the file
    file.close() ;

} // end of function
```

The above two functions are a part of a member function loadConfiguration of OsiManager class which is being called in the main function.

**My problem is I want these files Gabor filter and Application points  to be read into the variables at compile time as we do not want to upload the files to the cluster along with the executables or the build.**

Comment: It's especially not necessary that you confuse everyone with unrelated code. It's not possible to read any additional initialization data at compile time unless it's given in a format you can validly inject with an `#include` statement.

Comment: The linked to question is about binary data and does not allow for my solution which is to put the textual configuration data into the initialization string of a statically initialized `std::istringstream` object.

Comment: This technique might meet your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31953006/3807729

Comment: @Galik I was wondering if it would be possible to let the preprocessor inject text inside of a raw string literal (making the advantages of other pragmas like `#ifdef` etc. available). Trickery with string literal continuation or such perhaps?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just managed it but I had to put the raw string delimiters `R"~(` and `)~";` in the external text file.

Comment: @Galik Slick idea :-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ https://ideone.com/4wEIjS requires the external file starts with `R"~(` and ends with `)~";`. Messes up my IDE's syntax checking though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As I already told in the post I just wanted to give as much information as possible to make it easier to answer. Sorry once again for that. I have already looked at the answers to the duplicate questions but nothing has worked.

Comment: @Galik You mean if I use the technique you have used in your answer to the linked question  stackoverflow.com/a/31953006/3807729...I will be able to read the files at compile time. I really dont know the contents of the file. I just have the path of the file at compile time. I think you technique needs me to know the data right...I dont know I am a little confused. I am just new to all this C++

Comment: @user613037 The answer is essentially it's not possible, as I have mentioned in my 1st comment. That's also stated in the linked Q&A, hence I left your question marked as duplicate.

Comment: @user613037 Yes you need to have access to the data for that technique to work. Other answers might apply for you though like writing a small program to create a `C++` source file from your data file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do runtime file IO at compile time but since the source data is just text you can initialize a `const char*` string with the contents of those files (easy with C++11 raw string literals and copy and paste) and replace the `ifstream` in your init functions with a `std::stringstream` initialized with your string literal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how can I initalize the const char * string with the contents of those files. I just know the location of the file. I think thats my problem. How can I copy those contents and initialize that variable with those contents at compile time  I am sorry I am just too naive at these advanced concepts of c++. Can you give me an example of it.

Comment: Copy and paste I'm afraid... In some situations you could `#include` the contents of the file but I don't think that it is possible to turn a text file into a string that way.

Comment: If you want to automate reading the file you could set it up through your build system using some simple scripting or a tool like xxd.

Comment: As a matter of fact I did try the xxd and tried to # include the xxd generated header file such as mGaborFIlters={#include "filters.h"}...but I am not sure it gave me a lot of compile time errors and I dont think I did it the right way